# Loss of quality when I export raster image

Tags: r, image-processing

I would like to crop an image. I use crop function with a raster and then export the new image as .jpg. I use the same resolution of 96dpi as the original when I export. Dimensions are also the same.

As you can see the quality decreases. How can I solve that?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
img <- stack(list.files(path='C:/Users/PC/Desktop/R/Image test/', full.names=TRUE))

size = 64
gap <- 8

raster <- brick(img, package="raster")

xlim <- dim(img)[2]-(size*floor(dim(img)[2]/size))
ylim <- dim(img)[1]-(size*floor(dim(img)[1]/size))

cropping <- extent(0, dim(raster)[2]-xlim, 0, dim(raster)[1]-ylim)
img2 <- crop(img, cropping)

##############################################################
##############################################################
##location of the folder where you save
setwd("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/R/Image test/New folder/")

#To save/export  image into windows folder
jpeg(filename="Test15_b.jpg",
    width = (dim(img2)[2]), height = (dim(img2)[1]), units = "px", res = 96)
plotRGB(img2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Could you make this more reproducible? Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you upload the images separately, you can easily make this reproducible like this: `b = brick("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o0PE.jpg")